# Error to run IONIC 2 project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have download project from [project tutorial](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app). I am trying to run this  ionic 2 app using `ionic serve`.I got the error as bellow. How can i solve this error?

```
    G:\alka\ionic-conference-app-master\ionic-conference-app-master>ionic serve

> ionic-conference-app@0.0.0 ionic:serve G:\alka\ionic-conference-app-master\ionic-conference-app-master
> ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "undefined" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"

module.js:597
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\G:\alka\ionic-conference-app-master\ionic-conference-app-master\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at module.exports (G:\alka\ionic-conference-app-master\ionic-conference-app-master\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:19:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\alka\ionic-conference-app-master\ionic-conference-app-master\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ionic-conference-app@0.0.0 ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "undefined" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-conference-app@0.0.0 ionic:serve script 'ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "undefined" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-conference-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "undefined" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-conference-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-conference-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Patoliya-1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-04-27T05_55_17_136Z-debug.log
There was an error serving your Ionic application: There was an error with the spawned command: serve
```

bellow is my 'package.json' file,

```
     "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.5.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.1.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.5",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "config": {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `npm i` before running the project.That will install all the `node modules` which are needed for your project.

Comment: its also display error as `G:\alka\ionic-conference-app-master\ionic-conference-app-master>npm i
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})``

Comment: Those are warnings no? Did above command install node modules? see that on your file path.There should be folder name `node_modules` with hundreds of folders inside it.

Comment: i have tryied this `npm rm node-sass
npm install node-sass` and now its solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try updating the Ionic CLI?

```
npm uninstall -g ionic

npm install -g ionic

ionic -v
```

Let me know if that fixes it!